# How can I change the position of the "Abstract" title in Springer paper?

Tags: titles, two-column, abstract, sv-classes

I am writing a paper using \documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} for a Springer journal.  Journal format requires the title of the abstract (i.e. the word "Abstract", not the title of the article) seem independently on the upper left corner of the abstract text, like this:

"
**Abstract**

SNOW-V is a stream cipher proposed by Ekdahl et al. at IACR ToSC 2019(3) with an objective to be deployed as the encryption
primitive in 5G systems. The stream cipher offers 256-bit security and is ready for deployment in the post-quantum era, in
which as a rule of thumb (due to Grover’s algorithm), quantum security will vary as the square root of the classical security
parameters."

In my code,  the title "Abstract" is positioned with the abstract text at the beginning, like this:

"**Abstract** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae,
felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula
augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo.
Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem."

How can I position the title "Abstract"  as in the first case?  Below is my code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file template.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3
% for Springer journals.          Springer Heidelberg 2010/09/16
%
% Copy it to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article. Delete % signs as needed.
%
% This template includes a few options for different layouts and
% content for various journals. Please consult a previous issue of
% your journal as needed.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% First comes an example EPS file -- just ignore it and
% proceed on the \documentclass line
% your LaTeX will extract the file if required
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
    %!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
    %%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
    %%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
    %%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
    %%EndComments
    gsave
    newpath
    20 20 moveto
    20 220 lineto
    220 220 lineto
    220 20 lineto
    closepath
    2 setlinewidth
    gsave
    .4 setgray fill
    grestore
    stroke
    grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
%\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
\usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if availab

% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%burada itibaren ekledim%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{→}{$\to$}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrtime}
% fnpct instead of footmisc:
\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct}

% patch \maketitle:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\affaddr}[1]{#1} % No op here. Customize it for different styles.
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\usepackage[misc,geometry]{ifsym} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    
    
    
    \title{Title of the Article}
    
    
    
    
    \author{%
        Author 1 Name Surname \protect\affmark[1, 2] \and Author 2 Name Surname\affmark[1] 
    }
    \authorrunning{Esra Yeniaras \and Murat Cenk}
    %\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head
    
    \institute{ 
        \Letter  $ ~~~$Author 1 Name Surname \\
        $~~~~~~~~$author2@..edu  \\ \\      %  \\
        %             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
        %\and
        $~~~~~~~$   Author 2 Name Surname \at
        $~~~~~~~$   author1@..edu\\ \\
        $~~~~~$ \affaddr{\affmark[1]  Institution 1, Colorado,USA}\\ \\
        $~~~~~$ \affaddr{\affmark[2]  Instituton 2 , Ontario, CANADA}\\
        %\affaddr{\LaTeX\ University}%
    }
    \date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
    % The correct dates will be entered by the editor
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}  
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            \lipsum
            
            \keywords{bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3.} 
        \end{abstract}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \label{intro}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange that the journal wouldn't provide that out-of-the-box. I'd just add a paragraph break at the beginning of the abstract (using something like `\leavevmode\par`):

[image]

```
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}  
  \maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
    \leavevmode\par\lipsum
      
    \keywords{bla1 \and bla2 \and bla3.} 
  \end{abstract}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
```